# In a survival situation, what can I use from a green coconut palm?

Tags: survival, coconut-palms

Why is a coconut palm so valuable for a person in a survival situation?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ah, why wasn't this question already asked here!

- **As Food and Hydration:** If you are trapped on an Island (Refer: Castaway) probably Coconut Water can be only major source of potable water for you. As a bonus though, it contains a lot of nutrients, a great source of glucose and Potassium. Coconut meat, the white substance is totally edible, it contains Vitamin A and E.
- **Amazing Tinder:** Coconut tree petioles and leaves are fibrous, so they burn very well and produce a lot of charcoal which you can use as a fire-started. Also, the dry coconut shell will burn well.
- **Skin Care:** Coconut meat and Coconut Oil can also be used as a Sunscreen and/or as a Moisturizer.
- **Medical Usage:** One can squish coconut meat to get Coconut oil from it which has anti-fugal, anti-bacterial, anti-inflammatory, anti-microbial, anti-viral contents.
- **Hard shell:** A coconut shell cut into half can be used as a bowl, and the fresh green coconut can be used to carry nearly 500 ml water, depending upon size of the coconut.
- **Floats for emergency rafts:** Coconuts float very well,so if you at all you want to make a raft, you can pad coconuts below the logs.
- **String and rope:** The fiber threads extracted from a petiole of coconut tree can help you tie and lash many things, right from a hunting trap (wait, if needed) to as a shoelace.
- **Mats, clothes, and shelter:** The petioles of a coconut tree are perfect to make a shelter out of them. Weaving and braiding a mat, a wall, a hat, a plate, a bowl, or a carrying bag can be learned in a matter of minutes.

Comment: +1 but, maybe you could add something about how one gets a coconut open using only natural tools?

Comment: It's worth noting that, while it has many excellent properties, coconut is also a natural (albeit mild) laxative, which means a measured and balanced intake is a good idea in a survival situation.

Comment: Let's not forget - also useful for fabricating companions to fend off insanity... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYlWjxs3BSQ

Comment: pictures of palm-frond weaving and braiding: https://transpacifictrip.wordpress.com/2015/09/02/samoa-cultural-shows/

Comment: You can add coconut i.v. to your list, coconut water can be used as a short-term intravenous hydration fluid, supposing you know how to start an i.v..

Comment: @Brad, It's called an oldowan chopper. Ancient bi-pedal apes were able to figure out how to make them, so it should be easy for a *Homo-sapiens*.

Comment: @ShemSeger sounds like a great answer. Here's the [follow up question](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9880/breaking-a-fresh-green-coconut?lq=1)

Comment: Did you mean tinder in your second point?

Answer (score 2):

First you need climb the tree to get them. You need notch the tree to climb it. Then you need a large knife to cut them free. Up in the tree they swing in a circle.  You drop the green ones. Many will split open hitting the ground. Very hard to remove with out a large knife. They are soft. One slice done right with a knife the top is cut off. Drink the juice. Next cut in 1/2 remove pulp. They are not hard like you buy in the store. Unless old & brown. You can mash them between rocks. Go to jamesphilippines on imgur. There you will see us up the coconut trees here. You could find a hard volcanic stone Break & shape it. Then use it to notch & climb the tree. Pound them loose. Leaves are good for a makesift shelter. Also dried for fire wood. Light easy if well dried.