# How can I get a coconut from a tree?

Tags: coconut-palms

Inspired from this question [In a survival situation, what can I use from a green coconut palm?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/9863/2303), I wonder how can one possibly pluck a coconut from a coconut tree in safest possible ways.
We can also consider safer options like not having needed to climb the tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Climbing a coconut palm is actually pretty easy, though you do need to be fit in order to do it. You grab Around the trunk with you hands, and push off wish your feet and walk up the trunk.

It's easier if you can find a live Palm tree that has fallen over some but in this case you want to have good balance because it will be more like a balance beam then a trunk. If you can find a stick or hook like a boat hook that can reach the coconuts, you can hook the stem of the nut and give a good yank, but be prepared to jump back so it or they don't land on your head.

Comment: A word of caution here: Palm trees can have nasty splinters.